# OpenLDAP memberof Overlay configuration in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I'm having serious trouble configuring my OpenLDAP server to have the memberOf overlay enabled.
I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and installed my slapd from the standard apt-get repo.
All the instructions refer to editing the slapd.conf file, but I'm using the later version of OpenLDAP, which uses the dynamic configuration rather than the old static file.

I'm unsure whether the documentation is just not updated or if there is some configuration file I'm meant to be filling out?

[Documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Reverse%20Group%20Membership%20Maintenance)

Comment: You didn't mention any specific issue.  Are you at a complete loss where to start or are you getting an error message somwhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the memberof overlay using the dynamic config, add the following to your config database as a sub entry under the database that you want to enable it for.  In the example below replace the X and Y values with what is right for your setup.

```
dn: olcOverlay={X}memberof,olcDatabase={Y}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: memberof
```

You may also want to look into the referential integrity overlay as well so that group memberships are maintained on object renames.  If you don't have it setup and you rename/move an object the group will still contain the old value.  What this will do is scan the attributes listed in olcRefintAttribute for the DN that is changing and update the attribute with the new value.  Make sure you have indexes set on them or your performance will decrease.

```
dn: olcOverlay={X}refint,olcDatabase={Y}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcRefintConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: {X}refint
olcRefintAttribute: memberof member manager owner seeAlso roleOccupant
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what I'm supposed to replace X and Y with, I've tried various methods from the internet and they seem to end up in my slap.d config files, but nothing ever happens to my users (even when deleting all my users+groups and starting again)

Comment: They are sequential numbers starting at 0.  Config is normally 0.  In my setup Y is 2 because I have a config and monitor database setup.  Y for you could be 1 or anything greater depending on your setup.  X is the overlay number.  0 will probably work if you haven't configured any other overlays such as the password policy overlay.  In my setup I have the password policy (olcOverlay={0}ppolicy), memberof (olcOverlay={1}memberof) and referential integrity (olcOverlay={2}refint)overlays configured in that order.

Comment: Where do you see where your number should start? In my `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/` I have no files called olcOverlay but olcDatabase={1}hdb and olcDatabase{0}=config, I think I have 0 overlays, plus it's recently reinstalled and never added anything.

Comment: Should I put the text in a text file .ldif and use ldapmodify?

Comment: You don't need to add the `{X}` part at all. The server provides it.